# FragmentTransaction add() error

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I want to add a fragment to the main activity, but it shows me an `error` if i insert the fragment's *java* file object as the second parameter for the add method. I imported `android.support.v4.app.Fragment` and it didn't help.

Here is my code :

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    FragmentManager managerFragment;
    managerFragment = getFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction tranzactieFragment = managerFragment.beginTransaction();
    frg_jos FragJos = new frg_jos();
    tranzactieFragment.add(R.id.frg,FragJos);
}
```

Comment: I don't see you are doing .commit after adding the fragment https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/FragmentTransaction.html#commit()

Comment: As already pointed out, you’re missing a `.commit()` to your transaction. But also please, `frg_jos` is a very bad name for a Java/Kotlin class. It works, and it’s supported, but the _platform convention_ is to use `CamelCaseForClasses`. It will make your code easier to read for the rest of the world, which is helpful, for example, in this case where you need to share it. ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would write it like this:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    if (savedInstanceState == null) {        
         getSupportFragmentManager()
             .beginTransaction()
             .add(R.id.frg, FragJos.newInstance())
             .commit(); 
    }
}
```

and I would add

```
public static FragJos newInstance() {
    return new FragJos();
}
```

To your fragment. This is what Android/Google recommends. Don’t do `new XXXFragment()` directly, nor pass parameters via Fragment Constructor ([for restore state reasons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9245408/best-practice-for-instantiating-a-new-android-fragment?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)).

Answer (score 0):

Make it

```
    if (savedInstanceState == null) { 
       FragmentManager managerFragment;
       managerFragment = getSupportFragmentManager();
       FragmentTransaction tranzactieFragment = managerFragment.beginTransaction();
       frg_jos FragJos = new frg_jos();
       tranzactieFragment.replace(R.id.frg,FragJos);
       tranzactieFragment.commit();
    }
```

Comment: If you are going to use `add` then you need to ensure it’s protected from automatic reconstruction of saved state…  so it needs to be inside an `if (savedInstanceState == null) { getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.frg, FragJos.newInstance()).commit(); }`. That’s code I’d expect to see.

Comment: (I didn’t downvote, but I upvoted again, because your answer, albeit incomplete, does answer the question).